# where does the 'self' object comes from in the method __init__?

Tags: python, class, constructor, self, language-design

I'm learning python and the construct method `__init__` makes me confused.

```py
class Test(object)：
  def __init__(self):
    pass
```

As known, python implicitly pass a parameter representing the object itself at the first place. It is acceptable in common member functions. But what makes me confused is that **the constructor requests an object itself.**
It looks like the c++ code below. This code does not make sense! The parameter `thiz` does not even exit before the constructor!

```cpp
class Test {
public:
  Test(Test *thiz);
};
```

So, my question is, why python needs a "non-existent" `self` object in constructor `__init__`?

Comment: python **explicitly** passes a parameter representing the object itself.

Comment: `__init__` initializes an existing object; the object itself is created with `__new__`. this may help: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html

Comment: Because it's Python and not C++? You can also initiate attributes of a object in Python from outside the class, while C++ doesn't allow it.

Comment: An blog by Guido Van Rossum on this is a very good read : http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2008/10/why-explicit-self-has-to-stay.html

Comment: `__init__` is not a constructor, technically, in that sense. It is an *initializer*. The constructor is `__new__` which, obviously, doesn't take the instance as the first argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__init__` behaves like any other normal function in a class. It gets called by the interpreter at a special time if it is defined, but there is nothing special about it. You can call it any time yourself, just like a regular method.

Here are some facts to help you see the picture:

Function objects are non-data [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) in python. That means that function objects have a [`__get__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__) method, but not [`__set__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__set__). And if course they have a [`__call__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) method to actually run the function.

When you put a `def` statement in a class body, it creates a regular function, just like it would elsewhere. You can see this by looking at `type(Test.__init__)`. To call `Test.__init__`, you would have to manually pass in a `self` parameter.

The magic happens when you call `__init__` on an instance of `Test`. For example:

```
a = Test()
a.__init__()
```

This code actually calls `__init__` twice (which we'll get into momentarily). The explicit second call does not pass in a parameter to the method. That's because `a.__init__` has special meaning when the name `__init__` is present in the class but not the instance. If `__init__` is a descriptor, the interpreter will not return it directly, but rather will call `__get__` on it and return the result. This is called binding.

`a.__init__()` is roughly equivalent to `type(a).__init__.__get__(a, None)()`. The call `.__get__(a, None)` returns a callable object that is a bound method. It is like a special type of partial function, in which the first positional parameter is set to `a`. You can see this by checking `type(a.__init__)`.

The `self` parameter is passed to methods as the first *positional* parameter. As such, it does not have to be called `self`. The name is just a convention. `def __init__(this):` or `def __init__(x)` would work just as well.

Finally, let's discuss how `a = Test()` ends up calling `__init__`. Class objects are callable in python. They have a class themselves, called a metaclass (usually just [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type)), which actually defines a `__call__` method. When you do `Test()`, you are literally calling the class.

By default, the `__call__` method of a class looks something (very roughly approximately) like this:

```
def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    self = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    if isinstance(self, cls):
        type(self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

So a new instance is only created by `__new__`, not `__init__`. The latter is an initializer, not a constructor or allocator. In fact, as I mentioned before, you can call `__init__` as often as you like on most classes. Notable exceptions include immutable built-in classes like `tuple` and `int`.

As an initializer, `__init__` obviously needs access to the object it is initializing. Your example does nothing with `self`, but it is pretty standard to set instance attributes and do something things to prep the object. For cases like yours, an explicit `__init__` is not necessary at all, since a missing function will be found in the base class hierarchy.

Comment: this is a great answer...clarifies a lot of misconceptions. question tho, so in your `__call__()`  function example, there wouldn't be a need for the `__init__()` since you are making use `__new__()` and is there is a case where even `__new__()` is not required (can we bypass the constructor if so)?

Comment: @FishingCode. You can't bypass the constructor unless you use a custom metaclass. If you don't call `__new__` how do you expect to create an instance? You don't have to define `__new__` yourself of course, almost ever. It just gets looked up in the parent class.

Comment: @FishingCode. It's very rare, especially in classes implemented in python, to do the initialization in `__new__`. `__new__`'s only real job it to return a new empty object. The reason it accepts all the input parameters is for immutable cases like `tuple` and `int`, when it has to also initialize exactly once per instance.

Comment: that makes sense @Mad Physicist, always thought of the `__init__()` as a strict requirement. good point.

Comment: @FishingCode. Fun exercise. Write a metaclass that doesn't call `__init__` in `__call__`, and instantiate it with a class that has `__init__ = None` in the body. All child classes in that hierarchy won't have access to an `__init__` method. Normal class do because `type` uses it and `object` provides a default implementation.

Comment: that is a good test will check it out, for sure @Mad Physicist. there's a lot of info out there on SO but your explanations are great on this topic of understanding the purpose of an `__init__()` vs really just using a `__new__()` to accomplish the job of an actual constructor. cheers.